# How to export only one class (which uses another class) in TypeScript (CommonJS)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, export, commonjs

I implemented a "Least Recently Used Cache" (LRU Cache) using a doubly linked list. The linked list consists of nodes (`Node` class) which are used within a `LRUCache` class.

To export my module I am using the following pattern:

```
export class Node { ... }
export class LRUCache { ... }
```

I am exporting my module as a CommonJS module. With the `export class` pattern above, I am able to use my module the following way:

```
var module = require('lru-cache');
var cache = new module.LRUCache();
```

That's okay, but I don't like the additional "`module.`" part in front of `LRUCache`. I would like to use my CommonJS exported module like this:

```
var LRUCache = require('lru-cache');
var cache = new LRUCache();
```

So I changed my code into this:

```
class Node { ... }
class LRUCache { ... }
export = LRUCache;
```

But now TypeScript complains with:

> error TS4055: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using private name 'Node'.

It's because `LRUCache` uses the `Node` class and `Node` is not exported when defining `export = LRUCache;`.

How can I solve this situation? I am using TypeScript 2.1.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

With typescript you can simply do:

```
import { LRUCache } from "lru-cache";
let cache = new LRUCache();
```

And it will compile into:

```
var lru_cache_1 = require("./lru-cache");
var cache = new lru_cache_1.LRUCache();
```

If you prefer to use `require`, you can:

```
class Node { ... }
class LRUCache { ... }

export = LRUCache;
```

And then:

```
import LRUCache = require('lru-cache');
var cache = new LRUCache();
```

You can find much more info on this in the following two doc pages:

- [Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)
- [Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Comment: Thanks for helping but that's what I explained above. The problem is that I cannot compile the `class Node { ... } class LRUCache { ... } export = LRUCache;` code with TypeScript because with this only `LRUCache` is exported and it uses a class which is not exported (`Node`) and TypeScript doesn't like that.

Comment: Sorry about that, missed it. But what's wrong with the first approach of `import { LRUCache } from "lru-cache"`?

Comment: No problem. The thing is that I don't want to use my LRUCache (written in TS) with TypeScript. I want to compile it to JavaScript, so that I can use it in a Node.js application (which is based on vanilla JavaScript).

Comment: I see. How is the `Node` class used? I'm not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks for diving into it. I pushed it to GitHub. You can find it here: https://github.com/wireapp/wire-webapp-lru-cache/blob/greenkeeper/typescript-2.1.4/src/main/ts/LRUCache.ts

Comment: It's either not there or private because i'm getting a 404.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130959/discussion-between-benny-neugebauer-and-nitzan-tomer).